# Where to connect my NH-D15 SE-AM4 fan onto my ASUS PRIME X370-A motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, connection, fan, cooling

I have installed a [NH-D15 SE-AM4 fan](https://noctua.at/en/nh-d15-se-am4.html) onto my [ASUS PRIME X370-A](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/PRIME-X370-A/) motherboard :)

[image]

Although both fan/motherboard manufacturers provide some explanations, I'm confused as to where plugging the 2 CPU fans. These are the connectors I have:

[image]
[image]

**My question: where should I plug the 2 fans?**

*I'm assuming the main fan should go on `CPU_FAN`, but I have doubt about the second one, and I'm afraid it's going to mess things up.*

Comment: the NH-D15 should include a Y-cable. do you still have that?

Comment: You should be plugging both fans into the same header by using the provided Y-cable.  As to which header, per the directions in the manual for your motherboard, you should be using CPU_FAN.  CPU_FAN must be used, however if you have an additional fan, CHA-FAN2 can also be used.  All of this is clearly defined in the manual for your motherboard.

Comment: @Ramhound: I know it sounds obvious to you, but I haven't assembled a computer in 20 years, and I'm afraid of messing things up, hence the doubts and questions on SuperUser.

Comment: It takes no technical skill to read the instructions in the manual for the motherboard.  Descriptions of both headers are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Both [flolilolilo](https://superuser.com/users/703240/flolilolilo) and [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) provided the correct answer (confirmed by email from the fan manufacturer): use the `Y-cable` to connect both fans to `CPU_FAN`.